# NSPrintInfo changed in macOS Sierra

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have an application derived from the Xcode Cocoa Application template that prints properly on El Capitan, but introduces a centimetre margin all round with a shadow box on Sierra. Changing the margin values (in the shared instance in viewDidLoad of the viewController) to larger positive values makes the margins bigger, but reducing them to zero still leaves the margin and shadow box. The image is a screen-shot of the print preview. I would like to go back to having the PDF take up the whole printed page. Looking at the menu for the File/Print shows it executes firstResponder print:. Should I try to override this function? But if the code below is being executed to no effect, what good will this do?

```
NSPrintInfo *PageDefaults = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[PageDefaults setBottomMargin:0];
[PageDefaults setLeftMargin:0];
[PageDefaults setRightMargin:0];
[PageDefaults setTopMargin:1];
```

[image]

If I increase the top and left margins in the code above to 120, the print changes to:
[image]

The storyboard shows that I am only using a PDF View control that fills the entire viewController scene
[image]

And finally, the viewController on screen shows it looks as it should:
[image]

Comment: How do you print what? Maybe the view class changed. My simple test app doesn't print a border.

Comment: Not really a fair comparison to say that it works with a simple test app, as you probably created that yesterday in Xcode 8, whereas my app was originally created a couple of years ago in Xcode 5 or 6! Hopefully, my edit above makes the problem clearer.

Comment: The project was created in OS X 10.10 and Xcode 6.4. I'll try a PDFView. This isn't the only problem with PDFView in 10.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[PDFView print:]` in 10.10 calls `printWithInfo:autoRotate:pageScaling:`. In 10.12 `-[PDFView print:]` calls `printOperationWithView:` and prints the background. Solution: create a subclass of `PDFView`, override `print:` and call `printWithInfo:autoRotate:pageScaling:`.

```
- (void)print:(id)sender {
    [self printWithInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] autoRotate:YES pageScaling:kPDFPrintPageScaleToFit];
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you.